# Prove $T^2 = (T^*)T$ if $T$ is positive-definite

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, adjoint-operators, positive-definite

If $V$ is a finite-dimensional inner product space and $T: V\to V$ is an invertible, positive-definite (i.e., $\forall v \in V\backslash \{0\}, \langle Tv, v\rangle > 0$) linear map, prove that $T^2 = T^*T$ where $T^*$ is the adjoint of $T$.

In the case where $V$ is over the field $\mathbb{C}$, T is self-adjoint, but my proof of this relies on the fact:
\begin{equation}
\left(\forall v \in V, \langle Av, v\rangle = 0\right) \implies A=0
\end{equation}
which I've read doesn't hold in the real case.

Is there an alternative approach if $V$ is over the field $\mathbb{R}$, or better yet an approach that works over both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: If $T$ is positive definite, is it not redundant to demand that it must be invertible?

Comment: Yes, I guess so :P

Comment: I don't think it is true over the reals - take rotation by $\pi /3 $ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. This is positive definite, but it is not self-adjoint. (Incidentally, rotation by $\pi/2$ gives a counter example to your lemma over $\mathbb{R}$.) Can you include your argument?